# how to style a prompt text of combobox in java FX application?

Tags: css, combobox, javafx-2, styling

I want to modify the css style of my combobox  to reduce the text-size of its promptText.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to change size of the prompt text, and not the other text, I don't think there is any way: there's simply no hook into the text node for the prompt text that distinguishes it from the displayed text.

You can change the color via a special css property:

```
.combo-box .text-field {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) ;
}
.combo-box .text-field:focused {
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent ;
}
```

but I don't see any way to change any other style properties.

Comment: Are you sure this property works with combo boxes? I can't seem to make it work (JDK 7, Scene Builder 1.1). I have a form with multiple TextFields and 2 ComboBoxes. Even if I add a single css file with ".text-field { -fx-prompt-text-fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) ; }", all the text field hints turn red but the combo box hints stay as black.

Comment: Yup, tested on both JDK 7 and JDK 8. You might need to explicitly include `.combo-box .text-field {...}` in your css file.

Comment: Ok thanks - yes I tried that and many other combinations. Doesn't work for me - odd.

Comment: @JJ. does work for me either with all combination. please let me know if you got something

Answer (score 4):

just add the following codes at your css

`.combo-box-base .text{
    -fx-fill: rgb(130.0, 130.0, 130.0);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#combobox) out? Try something like:

```
.combo-box .list-view {
    -fx-font-size: xxxx;
}
```

You may need to specify additional properties/and or additional selectors to achieve the desired effect (e.g. `-fx-cell-size`). See the relevant section in `caspian.css` (located inside the `jfxrt.jar` in the `lib` folder of your JRE).

Answer (score 0):

With this code I change styles of comboboxes: font, font-size, text color etc.

```java
ComboBox<String> comboBox= new ComboBox<String>();
    comboBox.setPromptText("Text");

    comboBox.setButtonCell(new ListCell<String>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty); 
                    setStyle("-fx-font-size: 17.0");
                    if(!(empty || item==null)){
                        setText(item.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack using Scenic View

```
.combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-font-size: xxxx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As James D said this piece of code work in certain condition only

```
 .combo-box .text-field {
     -fx-prompt-text-fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) ;
 }
 .combo-box .text-field:focused {
     -fx-prompt-text-fill: transparent ;
 }
```

but only if you active **editable** property of your combobox.

If you add

`.combo-box-base .text`

it will apply even for the element of your combobox

If you don't want your combobox editable JavaFx don't take this into account. I think you have to manage it yourself by adding a PseudoClass and activate it yourself ...

Or put your combobox editable but forbid keyboard

Or You'll have to take another ComboBox from another Interface framework

**Those solutions are workaround** and not definitive solution i hope JavaFx developpers will improve this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, someone might get helped.

For default combo box:

```
 .combo-box{
     -fx-prompt-text-fill: #ffffff;
 }
```

For JFoenix Combo box:

```
 .jfx-combo-box {
     -fx-prompt-text-fill: #ffffff;
 }
```

You can also style the `.list-cell` `.label` `.text-field` sub-property(ies) if need be.